# If $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $A$ is open, is the set $A+B := \{ a+b \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$ still open?

Tags: real-analysis

I strongly suspect that $A+B$ should still be open, since $A+B$ is merely a translation of $A$. But how to give a proof or a counterexample to it?

Comment: It is not a translate of $A$. It is a union of copies of $A$ (one for each member of $B$). And that should tell you why it is open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct; if $A$ is open, then $A+B$ is open. To see this, write:

$$A+B = A + \bigcup_{b \in B} b = \bigcup_{b \in B}(A+b)$$

So $A+B$ a union of open sets of the form $A+b$. I leave it as an exercise to show that the translation of an open set is itself open. **Hint:** Fix any $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the function $a \in \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto a+b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Chou, not really. $r<b$ doesn't make sense, since $b$ is a vector.

Comment: Is it because, for every $a \in A$ there is an $0 < r < || b ||$ such that the ball $B(a; r) \subset A$?

Comment: @Chou, that isn't true. Consider $b=\tilde{0}$. Then no $r$ satisfies $0 < r <\|b\|$. Take a look at 5xum's answer if you prefer a more $\mathbb{R}$-centric perspective.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the existing answer is to go with more $\mathbb R^n$-centered definitions of open sets.

Take any element $x\in A+B$. Then you know there exists such $a\in A, b\in B$ that $x=a+b$. Now, since $A$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that the ball, centered at $a$ and with a radius of $\epsilon$, i.e. $B(a,\epsilon)$ is a subset of $A$. It is now easy to see that $B(a+b, \epsilon)$ is a subset of $A+B$:

> Take any element $y\in B(a+b, \epsilon)$. Then $y=(y-b) + b$, and the distance from $a$ to $y-b$ is equal to the distance from $a+b$ to $(y-b)+b=y$, therefore smaller than $\epsilon$. This means that $y-b\in B(a,\epsilon)\subset A$, so $y-b\in A$, meaning that $y\in A+B$.

meaning that $x$ is an internal point of $A+B$, so $A+B$ has only internal points and is therefore open.